# What are some examples of Models classes for client-side javascript that have hierarchy docs instead of flat rows?

Tags: javascript, model, client-side

I've checked out Backbone but it seems to lack hierarchy models :/ But I've also seen there is a plugin that fix it. Now I'm asking what are some better Models, instead of using the Backbone+plugin, that are built with hierarchy docs in mind in the first place and not patched it...

Thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

I found this: https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-deep-model which supports nested models...